# convert doc to docx using soffice not working

Tags: centos7, libreoffice, soffice

i am trying to convert a doc to docx using the following command:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to docx test.doc
```

I am using centos7, and install everything from openoffice throught

```
yum install openoffice
```

I am in the current directory of the .doc file.

I am having an error related to filters (I had search about these filters and didn't find one that would solve my problem):

```
Error: no export filter for teste.docx found, aborting.
Error: no export filter
```

Everytime i put some filter, it gives me another error:

```
Error: Please verify input parameters... (SfxBaseModel::impl_store <file:///path/test.txt> failed: 0x81a)
```

I put the filter (filter example from soffice) and still not working

```
soffice --headless --convert-to html:"txt:Text (encoded):UTF8"  --outdir /home/user/Downloads  /home/user/Downloads/test.doc
```

Comment: I also ran into this error, however, in my case it was because on the ```--output-dir``` I put the path like this: ```C:\path\to\file\``` when soffice actually expects ```C:\path\to\file```. Small mistake but gives the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discover why it's not working. I uninstall oppenoffice and libreoffice and put another one.

```
yum remove openoffice* libreoffice*
yum install libreoffice*
```

Probably it was missing some library or some dependencies were confliting.

Now everything is working.

```
soffice --headless --convert-to docx  teste.doc
```

Comment: I have the error message : Error: no export filter for C:\laragon\www\phpword\result\test.docx found, aborting.

Comment: @Gautier got any solution?

Comment: Syntax for LibreOffice 7 seems to be `--convert-to "docx:MS Word 2007 XML"`, with an output filter name supplied after the docx. Options for the output filter name ("MS Word 2007 XML") seem to be here: https://git.libreoffice.org/core/+/refs/heads/master/filter/source/config/fragments/filters

Comment: @JackCushman This looks like a promising suggestion, any chance you could contribute a full syntax as an answer?