# How can I resolve this issue and convert the DOCX file from the PDF Using LibreOffice in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, docx, libreoffice

I encountered the following error when running the below code:

Array
(
[0] => Error: no export filter for /home/nigsys.net/public_html/123.docx found, aborting.
[1] => Error: no export filter
)

Conversion complete. The Word file is located at output.docx

I am currently using LibreOffice version 5.3 on my server, and my PHP version is 7.3. I'm utilizing the following code, which employs LibreOffice commands, to convert a PDF file into a DOCX file:

```
<?php
 // Define the input PDF file and output DOCX file
 $inputPDF = '123.pdf';
 $outputDoc = 'output.docx';

 // Check if 'soffice' is recognized
 $libreofficeCheck = shell_exec('where soffice');
 if (empty($libreofficeCheck)) {
echo 'LibreOffice is not recognized. Please ensure that LibreOffice is installed, and its        directory is included in the system PATH.';
 } else {
// Command to convert the PDF to DOCX
   $libreofficeCommand = 'soffice --headless --convert-to docx --outdir ' . __DIR__ . ' ' . $inputPDF;

// Execute the LibreOffice command
exec($libreofficeCommand, $output, $return);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);

if ($return !== 0) {
    echo 'Error: LibreOffice conversion failed. Output: ' . implode("\n", $output);
} else {
    echo 'Conversion complete. The Word file is located at ' . $outputDoc;
}
```

}
?>

Both the PHP and PDF files are located in the same directory.

I want to convert a PDF file to a Docx file using LibreOffice. Please provide guidance on resolving this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert doc to docx using soffice not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277264/convert-doc-to-docx-using-soffice-not-working)